# Routing based on request headers using AWS Load Balancer or nginx

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, load-balancing, amazon-elb, aws-elb

**Scenario**: I have 2 clients. let's say client A and client B. Both clients have one common id (like UUID). My application(it's c++) is configured like both the clients have to connect in one server.

I am planning to add (AWS)ELB/nginx in front of my application. So **Problem** is when we received a request from client A it will pass through ELB and connect in one of the nodes. When client B sends the request to ELB then I am not sure that it will connect to the same node where client A is connected. Client B should connect on that node where Client A was connected.

**IN MY SCENARIO both clients should connect to the same node.**
Clients always come in a pair with a common id. 
WHAT should use in this case?

My application is dockerized and I am using kubenetes for deployments.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. You want each client to connect to the same backend, or you want them to connect to the same node but different backends?

Comment: Thanks for helping me @Crou Clients always comes in a pair with a common id. The 1st client will connect through ELB in one node than 2nd client should connect on that node where 1st client was connected. so I want to apply ID base load balancing.

Comment: If you need to connect to the same node then, as I wrote you can use `nodeSelector` or `Node affinity`.

Comment: I have multiple nodes and I want to route both requests from client A and client B to the same node from the ELB. Is this possible?

Comment: As far as I'm aware this is possible using [sticky sessions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html) on ELB side.

Comment: @SarjanPurohit did you find a solution for it ? what did you end up using ?

Comment: @user2225713 No

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your [`Nginx Ingress Controller`](https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx/kubernetes-ingress-controller/) and use `annotation`:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet
```

Your `Ingress` might look like the following:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
 set $agentflag 0;

 if ($http_user_agent ~* "(Mobile)" ){
 set $agentflag 1;
 }

 if ( $agentflag = 1 ) {
 return 301 https://m.example.com;
 }
```

Please check a more detailed explanation of [Annotations for ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md) on Github.

If you have more than one node, you can schedule `POD` on the same node by using [`Node affinity`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity-beta-feature). This can be also achieved by using [`nodeSelector`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) which is a simple version of `Node affinity`.